# Is imgur PDF upload broken?

Tags: bug, imgur

I just tried to upload a PDF via imgur and was told that I couldn't as it wasn't a jpeg, png (or some other image types that I've immediately forgotten).  This certainly used to work, has it stopped?  If so, can we get it reinstated?

Comment: Whenever I used imgur's PDF conversion feature I was always disappointed by the resulting image quality. Therefore I convert it to a PNG by myself now.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Nonetheless, it was still a useful feature.  Not every image has to be of great resolution.  Sometimes the picture is just to illustrate that the code works and fine detail is not needed.  The case where I noticed this was of a large oval filling a page - high resolution definitely not necessary!  So while I'll generate my own PNG where it matters, I also made use of the easy upload of PDFs to add images where otherwise I wouldn't have bothered.

Comment: Does nobody else use the screenshot->clipboard->paste pipeline?

Comment: @SeanAllred I use that when I want better resolution than the PDF upload.  I still maintain that the PDF upload is a Good Thing and a Useful Tool to have *in addition* to the other methods.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Can't argue with that - any tool available at your disposal is a good one.

Comment: The only work-around I've found is to upload the PDF to [Imgur](http://imgur.com/) (not the dedicated [se] one), and then re-upload it here using the "direct URL" (and possibly delete the original uploaded/converted image... just because you're nice to the Web).